# Need help simply validating if a field is text only

Tags: javascript

For now I have (this is from another already completed function)

```
function validatelength() {
    var length = parseInt(document.getElementById("length").value, 10);
    var lengthError = document.getElementById("lengthError");
    if (isNaN(length) || length < 50 || length > 220) {
        lengthError.innerHTML = ">>Please enter your height<<";
        return false;
    } else {
        lengthError.innerHTML = "";
    }
    return true;
}
```

this is my little code to check if the field contains really the length of a person.

Now for a text field (name/pre-name/notes) I want this too
So far I have

```
function validatetext() {
    var text = parseInt(document.getElementById("text").value, 10);
    var textError = document.getElementById("textError");
    if (isNaN(text) || text < 50 || text > 220) {
        textError.innerHTML = ">>Please enter text only<<";
        return false;
    } else {
        textError.innerHTML = "";
    }
    return true;
}
```

Could anyone help me completing the function? Thanks
BTW: I can't use jquery. (not allowed to)

Comment: @j08691 not for grades but it's an assignment yeah

Comment: "Text", to me, means "any printable character".  For clarity, you should specifically ask about "letters" or "alphabetical text".

Answer (score 3):

use regex to make sure only letters occur in the value.

something like

`/^[A-Za-z]*$/`

should work.  That regex says

"Match any letter from A-Z and a-z, from 0 to unlimited times, from the start of the line to the end of the line".

I am making the assumption that you don't want to accept anything that is not letters.

Comment: Not sure how to apply this to the function though..
Will if(textError.match(/^[A-Za-z]*$/) do?

Comment: why dont you try it...match returns an array of matches or null if there are none.

Comment: `/regexp/.test(string)` will return a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `textError` is the string you're evaluating as, and should be, text-only, I'd suggest:

```
if (textError.match(/\d/)){
    // there's numbers in this string
}
```

[JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/U7V6f/).

References:

- [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
- [JavaScript Regular Expressions, at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: You mean like this?


function validatetext() {
    var text = parseInt(document.getElementById("text").value, 10);
    var textError = document.getElementById("textError");
    if (textError.match(/\d/)){
        textError.innerHTML = ">>Please enter text only<<";
        return false;
    } else {
        textError.innerHTML = "";
    }
    return true;
}

Comment: I mean the above `if` test, using `match()`, will show if there are numbers in your string. As this is homework I'm reluctant to point you too far towards the solution, but this should certainly help.

Comment: this only catches numbers, not other non-text characters

Comment: yeah, I deliberately chose to allow punctuation characters, special characters and so on (given that text-only, to my mind, implies sentences, which may contain those characters).

Comment: @hvgotcodes I suppose it's up to the OP (or the OP's instructor) if `John Smith-Williams` will be allowed to enter his last name or not.

Answer (score 0):

Look, this implementation can help you the entire life, and if you are an student it's much more easier to explain than regular expressions.

```
//In this case I will define here the lower and upper case alphabet
//you can restrict this alphabet to match commas, spaces, or anything else, you just
//need to add them to the var.

var lowercaseLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzáéíóúñü"; 
var uppercaseLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÁÉÍÓÚÑ";

//This function will check if an specific letter "c" exist in the previous defined
//alphabet
function isLetter (c) 
{ 
    return( ( uppercaseLetters.indexOf( c ) != -1 ) || 
            ( lowercaseLetters.indexOf( c ) != -1 ) ) 
} 


//this is the Main Method, basically their function is split the Word "s" in all chars
//and check if those chars are defined in 
//the initials vars lowercaseLetters and uppercaseLetters

function isAlphabetic (s) {
   var i; 


    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i+=1) 
    {    
        // Check that current character is letter. 
        var c = s.charAt(i); 

        if (!isLetter(c)) 
        return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
}
```

Now, to call this function its very easy, you just need to capture the text from the Input and call isAlphabetic(text) where text is the captured text.

Answer (score 0):

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function checkIt(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    if (!((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123))) {
       document.getElementById("lengthError").innerHTML = "This field accepts numbers only."
        return false
    }
    document.getElementById("lengthError").innerHTML = ""
    return true
}

</SCRIPT>

<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="text" onKeyPress="return checkIt(event)">
```